# ¿Gesture detector no funciona dentro de un ListWheelView?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy haciendo un widget que pretendo que se muestre dentro de un ListWheelView, este widget, además va a funcionar como botón, para redirigir a una ruta que me interese. Por eso  el return tiene un GestureDetector, de esta forma, pulse en la parte que pulse del widget, funcionará como botón.
Aquí dejo el código del Widget:

```
class SelectActivityButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectActivityButton(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      required this.image,
      required this.routeName});

  final String text;
  final String image;
  final String routeName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () {
          if (kDebugMode) {
            print("Entrando a la actividad...");
          }
          Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(routeName);
        },
        child: Card(
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
            elevation: 10,
            child: ClipRRect(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  //Image.asset(image, height, widht)
                  const Image(
                    image: NetworkImage(
                        'https://www.yourtrainingedge.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/background-calm-clouds-747964.jpg'),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    child: Text(text),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            )));
  }
}
```

Y esta es la vista donde se muestra lo anterior, como dije, dentro de un ListWheelView:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeViewState createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<HomeViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => model.state == ViewState.busy
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              body: ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 300,
                  diameterRatio: 1.5,
                  offAxisFraction: -0.5,
                  children: [
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadCompras,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAlimentacion,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAgua,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadResiduos,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadTransporte,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                  ])),
    );
  }
}
```

He estado comprobando, tanto con puntos de parada como con prints, que el GestureDetector no está funcionando, he probado a ponerlo en la vista principal, y tampoco. ¿Que puede pasar? ¿Es acaso culpa del ListWheelView? Puesto que si uso el gesture detector en cualquier otro tipo de vista si que funciona perfectamente. Espero que haya alguna forma de solucionarlo.

**UPDATE:**
Actualizo con el codigo que funciona utilizando el paquete ClickableListWheelScrollView:

```
class HomeView extends StatefulWidget {
  HomeView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  HomeViewState createState() => HomeViewState();
}

class HomeViewState extends State<HomeView> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final _scrollController = FixedExtentScrollController();

  static const double _itemHeight = 300;
  static const int _itemCount = 5;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BaseView<HomeViewModel>(
      builder: (context, model, child) => model.state == ViewState.busy
          ? const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
          : Scaffold(
              key: _scaffoldKey,
              body: ClickableListWheelScrollView(
                scrollController: _scrollController,
                itemHeight: _itemHeight,
                itemCount: _itemCount,
                onItemTapCallback: (index) {
                  if (kDebugMode) {
                    print("Entrando a la actividad");
                    model.routingActivities(index, context);
                  }
                },
                child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
                  controller: _scrollController,
                  itemExtent: _itemHeight,
                  physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
                  diameterRatio: 1.5,
                  offAxisFraction: -0.5,
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
                    print(index);
                  },
                  childDelegate: ListWheelChildListDelegate(children: [
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadCompras,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAlimentacion,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadAgua,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadResiduos,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                    SelectActivityButton(
                      text: S.current.actividadTransporte,
                      image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
                      routeName: 'activityBuy',
                    ),
                  ]),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `ListWheelScrollView` intercepta todos los toques por lo que no se puede reconocer el `onTap` del elemento, ese Widget no fue pensado para eso.

Si usas el `ListWheelScrollView` deberías usar este método `onSelectedItemChanged` para obtener el seleccionado

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListWheelScrollView/onSelectedItemChanged.html

```dart
ListWheelScrollView(
                  itemExtent: 300,
                  diameterRatio: 1.5,
                  offAxisFraction: -0.5,
                  onSelectedItemChanged: (index){ 
                       //aquí muestra el elemento que está en foco.
                  }
```

**UPDATE**

Una forma de conseguir lo que deseas, es haciendo una implementación propia del `ListWheelScrollView` o usando un package, como este:

https://pub.dev/packages/clickable_list_wheel_view

Lo podrías usar de esta forma:

```dart
ClickableListWheelScrollView(
  scrollController: _scrollController,
  itemHeight: _itemHeight,
  itemCount: _itemCount,
  onItemTapCallback: (index) {
    // Aquí recibirás el evento cuando se toque el elemento
    print("onItemTapCallback index: $index");
  },
  child: ListWheelScrollView.useDelegate(
    controller: _scrollController,
    itemExtent: _itemHeight,
    physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
    overAndUnderCenterOpacity: 0.5,
    perspective: 0.002,
    onSelectedItemChanged: (index) {
      print("onSelectedItemChanged index: $index");
    },
    childDelegate: ListWheelChildBuilderDelegate(
      builder: (context, index) => _child(index),
      childCount: _itemCount,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Podrías ponerme un ejemplo de como se usaría?

Comment: ahí actualicé mi respuesta

Comment: Pero, que se tendría que poner dentro de onSelectedItemChanged, ya que index es eso, tan solo el indice, un int. No se me ocurre como haría para activar algo parecido a un onTap ahí dentro.

Comment: como mencioné en la respuesta, no se puede usar el onTap dentro del `ListWheelScrollView`, la forma correcta de hacerlo es usando el método que provee `onSelectedItemChanged`, que cuando deslices la rueda, se activará ese método cuando el elemento seleccionado este en el centro (con el indice del elemento)

Comment: ahí actualicé mi respuesta, usando un package puedes hacerlo

Comment: revisa mi respuesta actualizada

Comment: Estoy probando el paquete, pero supongo que es antiguo o algo, ya que agregar esto "clickable_list_wheel_view: latest_version" a las dependencias da error en "latest_version". Quitando eso parece ser que lo instala, pero luego no lo reconoce al tratar de añadir el widget.

Comment: usa esto : clickable_list_wheel_view: ^0.2.0

Comment: PArece que se instala pero sigue sin reconocer el paquete, te pasa tambien a ti?

Comment: Finalmente conseguí hacerlo funcionar. Es un poco lioso pero dejo la pregunta principal actualizada con el código que he utilizado para hacer lo que quería en un principio.

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que el GestureDetector no esté funcionando debido a que está dentro de un ListWheelView. Esto se debe a que el ListWheelView intercepta los gestos, por lo que el GestureDetector no es capaz de detectar los gestos. Para solucionar esto, deberás agregar un Listener a tu ListWheelView para que los gestos sean detectados.

Por ejemplo, aquí hay un ejemplo de cómo agregar un Listener a tu ListWheelView:

```
ListWheelScrollView(
    itemExtent: 300,
    diameterRatio: 1.5,
    offAxisFraction: -0.5,
    listener: (details) {
        // Aquí va el código para detectar los gestos
    },
    children: [
        SelectActivityButton(
            text: S.current.actividadCompras,
            image: "assets/compras/comida.png",
            routeName: 'activityBuy',
        ),
        // ...
    ]
)
```

De esta manera, los gestos serán detectados por el ListWheelView y el GestureDetector funcionará correctamente. Saludos y dime si te funcionó :)

Comment: Lo he probado, pero me dice que ListWeehlScrollView no tiene ningun atributo llamado "listener".

Comment: Es posible que el ListWheelScrollView esté bloqueando el evento de toque en el botón. Prueba agregando el siguiente código al ListWheelScrollView:

physics: ClampingScrollPhysics().

Esto le indica al ListWheelScrollView que no bloquee los eventos de toque.

Comment: Bienvenido, favor de leer el siguiente [artículo](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5462/pol%c3%adtica-temporal-chatgpt-est%c3%a1-prohibido), saludos

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no se ha usado CHAT GPT en ningún momento

Comment: @GonzaloKuns Tampoco parece funcionar